# CakePHP - JsonView rendering is sub function of the controller

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm using Cakephp with **json parse extension** and the **RequestHandler** component in order to create Web services using json.

I created a controller named `Ws`
In this controller I have a  named `userSubscribe`

In order to avoid a lot of `If else` statements in the next methods, I thought about using a private function inside this controller that will check somes conditions and stop the script normaly BUT ALSO render the json normaly. I just want to do a DRY way !

My question is :

**How could I render the json view in a sub function (called by the userSubscribe) ?**

To make it clear, here is the style code that would like

```
public function userSubscribe() {
    $this->check();

    // Following code only executed if check didn't render the json view
    // $data = ...
    $code = 1;
    $i = 2;
}

private function check() {
    $input = &$this->request->data;
    if ($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"] != "application/json") { // For example
        $result = "KO";
        $this->set(compact("result"));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'result');

        $this->render(); // HERE, it will stop the 'normal behaviour' and render the json with _serialize
    }
    if (!isset($input["input"])) {
        $result = "KO";
        $this->set(compact("result"));
        $this->set('_serialize', 'result');

        $this->render(); // HERE, it will stop the 'normal behaviour' and render the json with _serialize
    }
}
```

It's seems to be quite simple to do, but why can't I find the answer ?!

Thanks in advance for clue/advise/anything !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084490/cakephp-how-to-use-a-view-element-inside-of-a-controller follow this link

Comment: That's for getting the content of a view. Not want I'm looking for.